# laravel-eloquent where clause is from a relationship table two levels deep

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

How you go about this situation?
In laravel this is straight forward

```
$contracts = Contracts::with('bidinvitations')->with('bidinvitations.planentries)->where('created_at','2017-02-1')->get();
```

This works on the premise that in side the **where clause** the column (e.g **created_at**) must come from the parent table (contracts).

How do you query against a where clause from another table e.g

```
$contracts = Contracts::with('bidinvitations')->with('bidinvitations.planentries)->where('bidinvitations.planentries.created_at','2017-02-1')->get();
```

This query :
`where(**'bidinvitations.planentries.created_at'**,'2017-02-1')`

just isn't working

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$createdAt = '2017-02-1';
$contracts = Contracts::with(['bidinvitations' => function($bidinvitations_query) use($createdAt) {
                                $bidinvitations_query->with(['planentries' =>
                                    function($planentries_query) use($createdAt) {
                                        $planentries_query->where('created_at', $createdAt);
                                    }
                                ]);
                            }])->get();
```

Comment: @Cengkuru Michael Glad I could help! :)